# How to dynamically access class field by name

Tags: c#

I have this class:

```
public class City
{
    public string city;
    public float residence;
    public float industry;
    public float trade;
    public float total;
}
```

I want to access to the rows with foreach loop:

```
List<City> cities = new List<City>();
string[] rows = {"city", "residence", "industry", "trade", "total"};

foreach(string x in rows)
{
    Debug.Log(cities[5].x); // this doesn't work
}
```

`cities[5].residence` or `cities[5].total` works but i don't want to write it directly.

I want to reference to `residence` or `industry` like  `cities[3].x` How can I make it work this way?

Comment: read about Reflection in C#

Comment: `cities[5].GetType().GetProperty(x).GetValue(cities[5], null)`

Comment: Or you turn this object to an indexer and get a more javascript like syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using C#, which is object-oriented programming, I foster you to improve the encapsulation in your code: think behavior rather than data.

This means that `City`'s can be improved toward this goal in this manner:

```
public sealed class City
{
    private readonly string city;
    private readonly float residence;
    private readonly float industry;
    private readonly float trade;
    private readonly float total;

    public City(string city, float residence, float industry, float trade, float total)
    {
        this.city = city;
        this.residence = residence;
        this.industry = industry;
        this.trade = trade;
        this.total = total;
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> YieldProperties()
    {
        yield return city;
        yield return residence.ToString("R");
        yield return industry.ToString("R");
        yield return trade.ToString("R");
        yield return total.ToString("R");
    }
}
```

And usage becomes

```
List<City> cities = new List<City>();
foreach(string p in cities[5].YieldProperties())
{
    Debug.Log(p);
}
```

So what did I change ?

- I properly encapsulated the class fields to avoid them leaking outside (which decrease your code maintainability)
- I provided instead a behavior: the capability to yield itself each element one by one as a string
- I used `sealed` and `readonly` to make the class immutable (which is a good practice for maintainability)
- I removed the obsolete variable `rows` which is very dangerous: renaming a field in `City` would break your code if you forgot to update `rows` content
- I **didn't** use any reflection, which I believe should be avoided as much as possible